# Proper regular expression for server error message

Tags: java, javascript, regex, error-handling, alert

I am making an Ajax call, and I am getting an error from the server.

Now the problem is I am getting the below message.

```
HTTP Status 756 - Error while processing the request.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message Error while processing the request.

description Cannot find message associated with key http.756
```

And I want to get only the error message from the complete error report, not all the text above. How can I do that?

But the actual response is

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/5.0.28 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 756 - Error while processing the request.</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Error while processing the request.</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>Cannot find message associam<D‡üñÔE(1@@ähttp.756</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/5.0.28</h3></body></html>​
```

From where I want to get the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer by the following JavaScript code.

```
var res = "Error Message : '";

var bonly = data.responseText.match(/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/);
if (bonly && (bonly.length > 1)) {
    res += bonly[1];
}
res += "'. Error Code : ";
res += data.status;
return res;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you get the `response` HTML back, you can grab the message like so...

```
var div = document.createElement("div");

div.innerHTML = response;

var errorMsg = [].filter.call(div.getElementsByTagName("b"), function(b) {
    return b.textContent == "message";
})[0].nextElementSibling.textContent || "Unknown error";
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xEMCj/).

---

If it were just text...

This will extract the text after the `-` on the first line. If it can't find a match, it will return "Unknown error".

```
var errorMsg = (response.split("\n")[0].match(/^HTTP Status \d+ - (.+)$/) 
                || [])[1]
                || "Unknown error";
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCxqT/).

If instead, you wanted to match the `message` line below.

```
var errorMsg = (response.match(/^message (.+)$/m) || [])[1] || "Unknown error";
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRQWy/).

Comment: Isn't it better to catch `message (.*)` ?

Comment: @hsz They appear to be the same thing in the OP's example.

Comment: Sure, just woke up. Have a nice day ;-)

Comment: @hsz I added an example too on how to do that :)

Comment: @BhavikAmbani That's something that should have been included in your original answer. Can you post the HTML then?

Comment: Please see the edited question, from where I want to get the error code and error message.

Comment: @alex What is the above thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this working example:  [Regex](http://regexr.com?31j88)

```
(?<=-\s).*
```

OR

```
(?<=[0-9]\s-\s).*
```

This would fetch the exact mesage: `Error while processing the request.`

**EDIT**

If it contains `HTML` then this will work: [Updated Regex](http://regexr.com?31j8h)

```
(?<=<h1>).*(?=</h1>)
```

Comment: Means you are getting the Result in `HTML` format..if yes, can you specify that in the question..?

Comment: Please see the edited question, from where I want to get the error code and error message

Comment: JavaScript regexes don't support lookbehinds.